# STM32 " undefined reference to `HAL_DELAY'"

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, arm, stm32

I used STM32 Cube MX to generate a makefile project. I'm using vs code as an IDE. I wanted to add a file Display.C/Display.H file to write a display driver. However when I call "HAL_DELAY()" I get a C:\Users\josep\Desktop\STM32\Display_2/Core/Src/Display.c:18: undefined reference to `HAL_DELAY'

Im including the #include "stm32g4xx_hal.h" where HAL_DELAY is defined.

I can use some help. See below fore Makefile and code

MakeFile

```
# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = Display_2


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Core/Src/main.c \
Core/Src/stm32g4xx_it.c \
Core/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_msp.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_uart.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_uart_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_exti.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_dma_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_spi.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_spi_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Core/Src/system_stm32g4xx.c  \
Core/Src/Display.c 

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32g431xx.s


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32G431xx


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-ICore/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32G4xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32G431RBTx_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
  
#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)
```

Display.h---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#ifndef __DISPLAY_H
#define __DISPLAY_H

#endif

#include "stm32g4xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32g4xx_hal_conf.h"

extern void LCD_Reset(void);
void LCD_Write_Command(uint8_t data);    
void LCD_WriteData_Byte(uint8_t data); 
void LCD_WriteData_Word(uint8_t data);
void LCD_Init(void);
void LCD_SetWindow(uint8_t Xstart, uint8_t Ystart, uint8_t Xend, uint8_t  Yend);
void LCD_SetCursor(uint8_t X, uint8_t Y);
void LCD_Clear(uint8_t Color);
void LCD_ClearWindow(uint8_t Xstart, uint8_t Ystart, uint8_t Xend, uint8_t Yend,uint8_t color);
void LCD_DrawPaint(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t Color);
```

Display.c-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include "Display.h"
void LCD_Reset(void)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_10,1); 
    HAL_DELAY(200);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_10,0); 
    HAL_DELAY(200);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,0); 
    HAL_DELAY(200);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,0); 
    HAL_DELAY(200);
}
```

main.c--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Display.h"


UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init(); 
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  
  LCD_Reset();
  while (1)
  {
    
    
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAL_DELAY()` is actually written `HAL_Delay()`, i.e. with four lower-case letters.

Little things like these matter in C.

Comment: This question should be closed as problem was caused by typo.